# How can I add a Label next to each of my programmatically added TextBoxes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating TextBoxes dynamically/programatically from code behind using a for next loop (based on record count of database entries) and populating those textboxes accordingly. That part is working just fine.
What I want to do is add a "Label" next to each one of those textboxes, say, immediately to the left of each TextBox. I'll take care of the populating of those labels, I just have no idea how to make the placement of the labels happen. I know I came across something that looked like a solution once on this forum but have never been able to relocate it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
For i = 1 To 20
Dim TextBoxes As New TextBox
TextBoxes.ID = "RS" & i
TextBoxes.Text = Slot.Rows(0)(Ri).ToString()
TextBoxes.Attributes.Add("class", "slotFields")
PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(TextBoxes)
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want a pair of `Label/TextBox` in one row, so you could use `Panel` to group the `Label` and `TextBox` first, then add the `PlaceHolder` after

```
For i = 1 To 20
    Dim p = new Panel()
    Dim lab = New Label()
    lab.Text = "label" & i
    Dim TextBoxes As New TextBox
    TextBoxes.ID = "RS" & i
    TextBoxes.Text = Slot.Rows(0)(Ri).ToString()
    TextBoxes.Attributes.Add("class", "slotFields")

    p.Controls.Add(lab)
    p.Controls.Add(TextBoxes)

    PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(p)
Next
```

Comment: Perfect solution... opens a bunch of possibilities for other projects.